# Git(hub) remove older commits

Tags: git, github, commit

I made some trash commits that I don't want to have anymore

Let's say I made some minor changes and committed after each change. But I only want to push from last my last commit on to github. Here's how my history looks:

```
Initial commit --> Second commit --> Third commit --> Fourth commit
```

Only my fourth commit is good enough to push to github, so how could I delete commit 1 to 3 but keep 4?

I tried to google for my problem, but I could only find out how to delete the newest commit or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could not delete oldest commits if the newest commit depends on them. If not :

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

And delete unwanted commit by deleting corresponding line.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git revert <commit>` where `<commit>` is the hash of that commit shown in git log. Basically it will create another commit which will revert back changes done in the specified commits.
Here are the steps:

1. `git log` and note the hashes of commit `1-3`
2. `git revert <commit 1>`, `git revert <commit 2>` and `git revert <commit 3>`
3. Now you will be having additional `three commits` which will revert changes of commit `1-3`.
4. `git rebase -i HEAD~7` this will squash your 7 commits into 1.
5. When prompted, edit `commit 4` whose commit message you want to push as `pick` and change others to `squash`.

For more info see [this](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html)